# How update a dataframe column value from second dataframe where values on two specific columns that can repeat on first match on both dataframes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes with different information about a person, on the first dataframe, person's name may repeat in different rows. I want to add/update the first dataframe with data from the second dataframe where the two columns containing person's data matches on both. Here an example on what I need to accomplish:

```
df1:
     name    surname
0    john    doe
1    mary    doe
2    peter   someone
3    mary    doe
4    john    another
5    paul    another

df2:
     name    surname    account_id
0    peter   someone    100
1    john    doe        200
2    mary    doe        300
3    john    another    400

I need to accomplish this:

df1:
     name    surname    account_id
0    john    doe        200
1    mary    doe        300
2    peter   someone    100
3    mary    doe        300
4    john    another    400
5    paul    another    <empty>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can try this: df1 = df1.merge(df2, on=['name', 'surname'], how='left')

Comment: ```pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['name','surname'],how='left')```

Comment: Thanks! That worked as expected